# Is this document likely partly sufficient to obtain a USA medical visa?

Tags: visas, usa, health

I'm thinking of applying to the USA embassy in London for a medical visa.  One of the requirements is of course for details from my doctor in my country, U.K.

Although from 2012, I'm looking for your assessments. Is the letter below likely enough to suffice this element for my application to them?

[image]

The edited letter below begins "TO WHOM IT MAY CONCERN".  It gives my name, address, health number and d.o.b.

Comment: @chx There is no policy against that, if he is ok with it, then why not. I also do not think it is a good idea, but it is totally his choice.

Comment: @NeanDerThal the original image is still visible for anyone w/ edit privileges... I tried to flag to get moderator's attention to it :/

Answer (score 2):

The US State Department explains what documents you will need with respect to your medical condition to [obtain a B-2 visa for medical treatment](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html):

> If you are seeking medical treatment in the United States, the consular officer may ask for further documents at your visa interview, which may include:
>
> - Medical diagnosis from a local physician, explaining the nature of the ailment and the reason you need treatment in the United States.
> - Letter from a physician or medical facility in the United States, stating they are willing to treat your specific ailment and detailing the projected length and cost of treatment (including doctors’ fees, hospitalization fees, and all medical-related expenses).
> - Proof that your transportation, medical, and living expenses in the United States will be paid. This may be in the form of bank or other statements of income/savings or certified copies of income tax returns (either yours or the person or organization paying for your treatment).

It is clear that the document you posted would not be sufficient to meet the first requirement; it does not fully explain the medical condition and does not explain at all why treatment in the United States is necessary or advisable.

Comment: Ok, so this is about meeting the first paragraph part you posted only.  Not it all.  I want to ensure I have this part done if I can.  It doesn't state for it to be fully explained.  My doctor thought this enough, for me.  I'm not clear I must add on why you believe it doesn't say enough about necessity and being advisable for me to be seen in USA.

Comment: @ChristopherWright The letter you posted only describes your medical condition as a "broad accent". A brief visit to Google tells me that that is not a medical term for any sort of speech disorder. If I were the consular officer, and I did _not_ see the medical explanation, I would be suspicious. So I would recommend you obtain documentation of the specific condition, in medical terms, along with your doctor's explanation of why treatment _specifically in the United States_ is necessary.

Comment: I don't know what medical terms there are if any about speech.  For me even pinpointing a relevant profession is difficult. All fair comments Michael Hampton, but you don't think the references about my speech, accent and people cannot understand me to be enough?  It's debates leeway "abroad" means, not excluding USA from my country, but what explanation could be given for this without any names of American practitioners?

Comment: @ChristopherWright There are many, many types and causes of [speech disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_disorder). You'll probably want to get a referral to a [speech language pathologist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech-language_pathology) (known as [speech and language therapist](http://www.nhscareers.nhs.uk/explore-by-career/allied-health-professions/careers-in-the-allied-health-professions/speech-and-language-therapist/) in the UK) for a full diagnosis, if you haven't already. If you have, then this information should already be in your medical records.

Comment: Michael, since at least 1990 referrals have been made, always in my adult life.  I believe most diagnoses are made in children.  2-3 times I believe I've been seen by them. Mthen, they refuse other professionals referrals since some time in the 1990s.  I've never known, nor has it been spoken of, my diagnosis.  So there isn't one that I know for me. My doctor doesn't know it as far as I know.  So given this, I can I can only try to get seen, if you're definitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, the letter is unclear about the referrals. I took it to mean that you had been given referrals and had refused them, not that NHS (I guess) had refused to pay for/allow any more referrals. Perhaps you can save up and see a private speech therapist or pathologist to try to get a diagnosis? Otherwise, how are you going to find appropriate treatment outside the UK?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear whether you will actually need to apply for a visa at all. The category "medical treatment" falls under a [B-2 Visitor Visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visitor.html), which is the visa that virtually all tourists will get. Assuming you are a UK citizen, you are likely eligible for the [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) which allows the same activities as a Visitor (B) visa, including medical treatment.

A restriction that may apply to you is the maximum stay of 90 days under the VWP. Given that you cannot "travel for long periods abroad", this is unlikely to be a problem.

If for some reason you do not qualify for the VWP, you may still apply for a B-2 visa. However there is no requirement to justify your need for medical treatment in such an application.